# Wikipedia API and Response Language

Tags: jquery, wikipedia-api

I am using this JQuery Call to get Data from Wikipedia:

```
var searchTerm="Steve Jobs";
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=mobileview&format=json&page=steve%20jobs&redirect=yes&sections=all&prop=text&language=de";

$.getJSON(url,function(data){})
```

and it works, the problem is, the Response is returned in English, but i want it to be German

I tried to change the Url to de.wikipedia.org, but this returns a "page not found error"

Are there any Params that i can set to force the response in JSON to be another Language than English?

thx for help

Comment: You should use the actual [search api](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) first and based on results fetch the page.

Answer (score 0):

The `de.wikipedia.org` page link works but not with redirects in this case

http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=mobileview&format=json&page=Steve%20Jobs&redirect=yes&sections=all&prop=text

Notice the capitalization "steve jobs" to "Steve Jobs"